# In a custom module I override the cart item template

Tags: magento2, overrides, magento-2.0.7

How do I correct my code to fix this?

In my custom module I have the file `app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="simple" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions" as="actions">
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My custom template is in `/app/code/MyCompany/MyModule/view/frontend/templates/cart/item/default.phtml.`

I have tried removing the block first, then it doesn't load anything. Any help how to do this the right way is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new layout file named **checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml** in your layout folder at the following path:

**app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/**

Use the following code under **body** tag in this file:

```
    <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers">
        <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer" as="default" template="Vendor_Module::cart/item/default.phtml">
            <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions" as="actions">
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Edit" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.edit" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/edit.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Item\Renderer\Actions\Remove" name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default.actions.remove" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/item/renderer/actions/remove.phtml"/>
            </block>
        </block>
    </referenceBlock>
```

Using this code, you can override cart/item/default.phtml file in your module. Follow the same practice for other type of products.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override product specific referenceBlock to change the default template file as below in your custom `checkout_cart_item_renderers.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.bundle" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.virtual" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.default" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.simple" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.configurable" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.item.renderers.grouped" template="MyCompany_MyModule::cart/item/default.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```